# Как получить User Agent через HttpClient?

Tags: c#

Есть код который при запуске локальной страницы в браузере возвращает User-Agent браузера:

```
public static class UserAgentDetector
{
   private static int port;
   private static string useragent;

   static UserAgentDetector()
   {
      port = new Random().Next(13000, 14000);
   }

   public static string GetUserAgent()
   {
      try
      {
         StartServer(port);
         Process.Start($"http://localhost:{port}");
         long ticks = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
         while (useragent == null && new TimeSpan(DateTime.Now.Ticks - ticks).TotalSeconds < 60.0)
         {
            Thread.Sleep(100);
         }
      }
      catch { }
     return useragent;
    }

    private static void StartServer(int port)
    {
       HttpListener httpListener = new HttpListener();
       httpListener.Prefixes.Add($"http://localhost:{port}/");
       httpListener.Start();
       new Thread(Listen).Start(httpListener);
    }

    private static void Listen(object listenerObj)
    {
       HttpListener obj = listenerObj as HttpListener;
       HttpListenerContext context = obj.GetContext();
       useragent = context.Request.Headers["User-Agent"];
       HttpListenerResponse response = context.Response;
       response.Redirect("https://google.com/");
       response.Close();
       obj.Stop();
    }
}
```

Хочу сделать в `HttpClient'e`, но не знаю как.
И можно ли получить User-Agent без открытия браузера?

Comment: Хотите получить что? Ответ от сервера? Ну так отправляйте туда запрос, это ведь вызов одного метода ([.GetStringAsync()](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.getstringasync)). Вопрос то в чем? Где ваши попытки решения задачи? Где хоть один `HttpClient` в коде?

Comment: UserAgent передаёт на сервер сам браузер. Причём у каждого браузера он может быть свой. Соответственно, нужно запускать именно нужный браузер, чтобы получить его UserAgent. Сервер не имеет UserAgent. PS: задайте значение константой в своём коде и всё.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, Хочу получить User-Agent браузера через `HttpClient`, если это возможно. Вопрос в том можно ли изменить данный код под мои нужды? Какой запрос нужно отправить Get или Post ? А куда именно отправить? И можно ли не открывая браузер получить результат? ( простите, много вопросов задаю, новичок)

Comment: Какого браузера? При чем тут `HttpClient`? При чем тут `HttpListener`? При чем тут вообще `UserAgent`? Сейчас ваш код запускает свой сервер, который принимает запросы по указанному адресу, далее вы получаете нужный заголовок (`useragent = context.Request.Headers["User-Agent"];`) и отправляете на гугл. Ок, UserAgent подключенного клиента у вас должен быть в соответствующей переменной, дальше что? При чем тут `HttpClient`? Он служит для того, чтобы зайти на сайт и получить от туда его ответ, какой вы хотите ответ от вашего сервера, который редиректит на гугл?

Comment: Ещё раз: ни один сервер не имеет UserAgent. Поэтому никакой Get или Post запрос не сможет его получить.

Comment: Удалось разобраться?

Comment: @aepot, пока нет

Comment: @aepot, ответ можно было и не удалять. по-моему, вполне годный.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin автору не зашло, плюс я особо не вижу пользы для SO от своего ответа. Просто одно дело когда человек по незнанию путается, а совсем другое, когда ты ему объясняешь, а он не верит, не понимает или не хочет понимать. Читать документацию видимо тоже не хочет. Ну дело же добровольное, пусть верит во что хочет, у нас свобода вероисповедания. Я во всяком случае попытался.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем вопросе упомянуты три сущности: сервер (его роль исполняет HttpListener), браузер, HttpClient.

Только один из них - браузер - имеет UserAgent. В каждый браузер забита константа с его описанием. При выходе новой версии браузера это значение может меняться. Именно это значение браузер передаёт на сервер (веб-сайт). Сервер может использовать полученный UserAgent по своему усмотрению. Например, если его нет, то это скорее всего бот и можно не отвечать ему.

Две другие сущности: сервер и HttpClient - не имеют своих собственных UserAgent. Поэтому используя только их (а именно это вы и хотите сделать) неоткуда взять это значение.